# Can I make a word going through another word?

Tags: scrabble

For instance the word PLAY is on the board, and I put BOARD using the A from PLAY. Is that acceptable?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can play words just like in a crossword puzzle. As long as the words are left to right or top to bottom.

There are three ways to connect words (except for the first word.

First, connect it like a crossword:

```
  B
  O
PLAY
  R
  D
```

Second, extend a word:

```
LIVE
```

add an S

```
LIVES
```

Third, put a word next to another word so the neighbors form new words:

```
PROP
```

Add Idiot forming also PI

```
PROP
   IDIOT
```

And yes you can combine the last two to add a word to the end:

```
TREE
```

Add SEVEN

```
TREES
    E 
    V
    E
    N
```

Comment: This is, in fact, the primary method of adding words to a scrabble board.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus Other than the first play of a game, isn't it not only the primary way, but a completely required way?

Comment: @Gendolkari well, you can also extend words, which I was counting as different.

Comment: I see how it could be viewed either way. It's fair that there is a difference; but I was seeing the similarity of "must use existing letters on the board".

Answer (score 5):

Not only *can* you do this, you *must* do this!

Other than the first play of the game, when the board is empty, all plays must connect to existing words by forming new words out of the already-placed letters.

From [scrabble.hasbro.com](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/rules):

> The second player, and then each in turn, adds one or more letters to those already played to form new words.
>
> New words may be formed by:
>
> - Adding one or more letters to a word or letters already on the board.
> - Placing a word at right angles to a word already on the board. The new word must use one of the letters already on the board or must add a letter to it. (See Turns 2, 3 and 4 below.)
> - Placing a complete word parallel to a word already played so that adjacent letters also form complete words. (See Turn 5 in the Scoring Examples section below.)

Notice that in all 3 methods of forming a new word, the new word connects to an existing word, and uses at least one letter from that existing word to form a new word.

Answer (score -3):

You can cross words over one another like this

```
        E
        P
   S  O O N
        X
        Y
```